# Reading from a file into a list and have each element go through the program

Tags: python, list, text-files

Sorry if the title is confusing.  What I want to do is have a text file (keywords.txt) read and then split into a list.  So basically lets say the file contained "iphone, keys, wallet, pen, folder", I would want the list to be [iphone, keys, wallet, pen, folder].

Is there any way to set one variable to work for each element.  Say the variable is query.  Is there anyway for query to be each of the elements so it can go through the program and work for each element.  Below is the code I have, it obviously doesnt work but that is what I want to happen if possible.

The reason I want to do it for each is because eventually the script will write a new text file for each of the elements and name it based on what the element is and the only way I know how to do that is by having one variable.

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open('keywords.txt', 'r')]

try:
    query = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    query = item in data
```

Here is the rest of the code that I will be performing.  It will take what is in the list that is created and create a new textfile and a csv file.

```
newFile = open("%s.txt" %query, 'w').write(txt.encode('utf8'))

with open("%s.txt" %query, 'rb') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\n', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    with open("%s.csv" %query, 'wb') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: It'd be useful to provide **actual** input and your **expected** output - that'd help clarify what you're asking

Comment: So - if the `query` let's say `iphone` appears in the file, then you want a file called `iphone` containing what's in `keywords.txt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the `query` value taken from the command line into a list instead, then loop over the query list:

```
try:
    query = [sys.argv[1]]
except IndexError:
    query = data

for q in query:
    # do something with q
```

Comment: unless im missing something, making a list out of a single item, still only gives you a single item, so a for loop on the items in query, will be only 1 item. i dont understand what this is doing exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  It is close to what I need but when I run this with the rest of my code it doesn't do it one by one.  In the rest of my code I am creating a text file for each item in the list but it is just creating one text file for the whole list.  Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @Shmoe: create a new question with more details. I cannot mindread, I'm afraid.

Comment: @InbarRose: It's being able to use *either* a one-element list, or a full list, without having to special case handling of that one element given by the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_keywords_in_file(file_name):  
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            process(line.strip())

def process(keyword):
    #your code
```

if you want to write a new file with the name of the keyword:

```
with open('%s.txt' % keyword, 'w') as fw:
    fw.write('content')
```